# Pass Python list as a input to Redshift in SQL

Tags: python, sql, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I want to provide a Python list

```
sql_foramt= ['HP7CXNGSUFEPZCO4GS5RQPY6XY', '9475EFWZCNARPEJEZEMXDFHIBI', 
             '6ECWZUQGEJCR5EZXDH9URCN53M', 'XZ9P6KTDGREM5KIXUO9IHCTKAQ']
```

as a input to above SQL query in Python.

```
cur.execute("""CREATE TEMP TABLE ##Validation_Marc  (
Codes varchar(250) );


INSERT INTO ##Validation_Marc
VALUES

{}.format(','.join(list_name);
```

I'm trying to run the SQL query via Python using `psycopg2` library. I have tried the above method, but every time I try I get the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 48, in
>  psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "{" LINE
> 8: {}.format(','.join(list_name);

I'm unable to move forward , plese help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things are at issue in your code:

- Running two separate SQL commands in a `cursor.execute` call. This is a misunderstanding of Python DB-APIs which usually allows only one command per execute call.
- Improperly including `format` keyword *inside* the string. This is a general Python syntax issue of string interpolation. Specifically, `.format` is a method to be run on a string. See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#the-string-format-method).

Consider separating both SQL statements and properly using `string.format` to interpolate `%s` placeholders with [parameterization](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html). For illustration, `.format` is called on a separate line.

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(...)

sql = "CREATE TEMP TABLE ##Validation_Marc ( Codes varchar(250) )"
cur.execute(sql)
conn.commit()


mylist = ['HP7CXNGSUFEPZCO4GS5RQPY6XY', '9475EFWZCNARPEJEZEMXDFHIBI', 
          '6ECWZUQGEJCR5EZXDH9URCN53M', 'XZ9P6KTDGREM5KIXUO9IHCTKAQ']

sql = "INSERT INTO ##Validation_Marc (Codes) VALUES {}"    
cur.execute(query = sql.format(', '.join(['(%s)' for _ in mylist])), # FORMAT PLACEHOLDERS
            vars = mylist)                                           # BIND PARAMS 
conn.commit()
```

Comment: when i'm trying above method , I'm getting Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 3, in <module>
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: INSERT has more expressions than target columns

Comment: Try to explicitly specify target column. See edit adding column name to append query.

Comment: Actually, I also had a redundant pair of parentheses around all `VALUES` tuples. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear how you want the list to be inserted, but let `psycopg2/execute` format the query for you:

```
import psycopg2
import json

conn = psycopg2.connect("...")
cur = conn.cursor()

sql = "CREATE TEMP TABLE __Validation_Marc ( Codes varchar(250) )"
cur.execute(sql)

mylist = ['HP7CXNGSUFEPZCO4GS5RQPY6XY', '9475EFWZCNARPEJEZEMXDFHIBI', '6ECWZUQGEJCR5EZXDH9URCN53M', 'XZ9P6KTDGREM5KIXUO9IHCTKAQ']
sql = "INSERT INTO __Validation_Marc VALUES (%s)"

# Option1: Insert each code as record set
for value in mylist:
    cur.execute(sql, (value, ))
conn.commit()

# Option2: Insert codes as one recordset comma separated
cur.execute(sql, (','.join(mylist),) )
conn.commit()

# Option3: insert as string as it is:
cur.execute(sql, (json.dumps(mylist),) )
conn.commit()

cur.execute("select * from __Validation_Marc")

for row in cur.fetchall():
    print(row)
```

Out:

```
('HP7CXNGSUFEPZCO4GS5RQPY6XY',)
('9475EFWZCNARPEJEZEMXDFHIBI',)
('6ECWZUQGEJCR5EZXDH9URCN53M',)
('XZ9P6KTDGREM5KIXUO9IHCTKAQ',)
('HP7CXNGSUFEPZCO4GS5RQPY6XY,9475EFWZCNARPEJEZEMXDFHIBI,6ECWZUQGEJCR5EZXDH9URCN53M,XZ9P6KTDGREM5KIXUO9IHCTKAQ',)
('["HP7CXNGSUFEPZCO4GS5RQPY6XY", "9475EFWZCNARPEJEZEMXDFHIBI", "6ECWZUQGEJCR5EZXDH9URCN53M", "XZ9P6KTDGREM5KIXUO9IHCTKAQ"]',)
```

**Note:**
I had to change the table name, my postgres db doesn't allow that name: